# spring boot not fetching data from external oracle database configured

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I want to configure oracle database with spring boot2.
I have developed the dao layer code and unit tested with embeded H2 database successfully. But now when i provide the datasource configuration details in applicaiton.yaml file, it is not able to retrieve the data from the external oracle database. No error is getting displayed.

Here is my configuration

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

**Service layer:**

```
@Autowired
SampleActivityLogRepository repository;

//inside a method
Optional<List<SampleActivityLog>> listOfActivityForToken = repository.findLogByAccNoandTokenIDOrderByDate(userId, example.getKey());
```

**Repository Layer:**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SampleActivityLogRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleActivityLog, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT L FROM SampleActivityLog L WHERE L.accountId = ?1 AND L.userId = ?2 ORDER BY L.createdDate desc")
    Optional<List<SampleActivityLog>> findLogByAccNoandTokenIDOrderByDate(String accNo, String userId);
}
```

**application.yaml:**

```
spring:
  profiles: dev

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: ERROR
    com.example.rest.Tokennotification: DEBUG

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = example.com)(PORT = 1875))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = sit)))
    username: mvcschenam
    password: support$12ab
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    database: H2
    #openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
```

What I have tried:

1. I have removed the h2 dependency from the pom.xml. but it threw error no 'url' configured for datasource
2. I have tried to remove autoconfiguration by using @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
   But it threw error that SampleActivityLogRepository is only a interface .. need to implement. But i do not see much logic here.. as the same code worked when connected to boot integrated database

I need to connect to external database but i am not sure what i am missing. I do not want to change my code as i believe it is pretty neat and working as well.
Please guide me what i can do here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your yml to:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev

  logging:
    level:
      org.springframework: ERROR
      com.example.rest.Tokennotification: DEBUG

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = example.com)(PORT = 1875))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = sit)))
    username: mvcschenam
    password: support$12ab
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    database: H2
    #openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
```

It seems that your datasource and jpa was below logging node not spring